# attempt to call method 'random' (a nil value) in Lua

Tags: lua, torch

Below is my code

```
require 'dpnn'
 require 'cunn'

 local deviceNumber = tonumber(os.getenv("CUDA_CARD_NR"))
 cutorch.setDevice(deviceNumber)

 local module = nn.Sequential():cuda()
 module:add(nn.Linear(2,1):cuda())
 module:add(nn.Sigmoid():cuda())

 criterion = nn.BCECriterion():cuda() -- Binary Cross Entorpy Criteria

 local targets = torch.CudaTensor(10):random(0,1)
 local inputs = torch.CudaTensor(10,2):uniform(-1,1)

 function trainEpoch(module,criterion,inputs,targets)
   for i=1,inputs:size(1) do
     local idx = math.random(1,inputs:size(1))
     local input, target = inputs[idx], targets:narrow(1,idx,1)
     -- forward
     local output= module:forward(input)
     local loss= criterion:forward(output,target)
     -- backward
     local gradOutput = criterion:backward(output,target)
     module:zeroGradParameters()
     local gradInput = module:backward(input,gradOutput)
     --update
     module:updateGradParameters(0.9) -- momentum
     module:updateParameters(0.1) -- W = W -0.1*dL/dW
   end
 end

 for i=1,100 do
   trainEpoch(module,criterion,inputs,targets)
 end
```

I am running above using the following command

```
CUDA_CARD_NR=1 luajit feedforwad.lua
```

It gives the following error

```
luajit: feedforwad.lua:13: attempt to call method 'random' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    feedforwad.lua:13: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x004064f0
```

I know that there is some error in the line

```
local targets = torch.CudaTensor(10):random(0,1)
```

But I am not able to figure out.

Comment: See http://lua-users.org/wiki/MathLibraryTutorial - might be missing a library name?

Answer (score 0):

> luajit: feedforwad.lua:13: attempt to call method 'random' (a nil
>   value)
>
> Is not "some error" and you should not have problems to figure out what is wrong because the error message tells you exactly what is wrong.

You tried to call the a method named `random` which happens to be a `nil` value.
This means that there is no function with that name and therefor you can't call it.

According to the reference documentation (which you should have checked befor coming here) the function is actually named `rand`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I want a cuda tensor with random values of 1 and 0. I also tried `torch.CudaTensor():rand()` it is also not working. Can you tell me what is the correct way of doing it ?

Comment: so you get the same error or what? does not work is not very informative.

Comment: Actually it does not satisfy my need. I want binary digit 0 or 1 in random number which is not generated by `torch.CudaTensor():rand()`.

Comment: I have no idea of torch, but according to the reference there should be a function bernoulli() that does what you want. this at least works for other tensor types.